# Iterating over subclasses with different properties

Tags: oop, inheritance, design-patterns, encapsulation

I am interested in a design pattern or best practice approach to the following scenario:

Let's say we have multiple subclasses that derive from a common interface:

```
public interface IPerson{
    string Name;
}

public class SomePerson : IPerson{
    string Name;
    bool hasAccess;

    bool GetAccessInfo(){
    //implementation
    }
}


public class OtherPerson : IPerson{
    string Name;
    int NumberOfPoints;

    int GetNumberOfPoints(){
    //implementation
    }
}
```

Now let's assume we have a class which has a collection of IPerson objects:

```
public class PersonHandler{
     public List<IPerson> People;
}
```

So the question here is how would you iterate over the People collection and still be able to use the individual subclasses' members and methods like GetNumberOfPoints or GetAccessInfo all in one iteration?

I don't like checking the type explicitly and I also don't like having the subclass specific methods be in the interface, because it kind of defeats the purpose of OO design.

Maybe ideally those shouldn't be in the same collection? I'm looking for a language agnostic answer.

Comment: I think it not about how to iterator which is a separate issue but the question is how do you call a method that is only in derived class with base point?

Comment: @zar You can do casting/type checking in order to call subclass functions/members. However, I don't think that's generally good practice.

Comment: Yes it is not. I remember somewhere I came across BBC coding standards, it was prohibited. The idea of OOP is to let the class do that thing and it knows the type but I know we do want to retrieve a result or property and that issue remains.

Comment: I have thought about this previously and I think the solution might be to apply visitor pattern but that pattern itself is one of more complex among all and not sure how commonly it is used.

Answer (score 2):

I agree that adding the specific methods to the interface would be a bad idea (not to mention a violation of the [Interface Segregation Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interface_segregation_principle)).

Pattern Matching is a common feature/practice in functional programming that has made its way into more object-oriented languages in recent years (introduced in C# 7 using the `is` operator as well as other constructs such as the `switch` statement, as shown below), and it refers to conditionally branching based on the shape of a given object and binding to its members without having to explicitly and unsafely casting the object.

I know you're looking for a language-agnostic answer, but here's what your problem above might look like in C#:

```
public interface IPerson
{
    string Name { get; set; }
}

public class SomePerson : IPerson
{
    private readonly bool _hasAccess;

    public SomePerson(string name, bool hasAccess)
    {
        Name = name;
        _hasAccess = hasAccess;
    }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public bool GetAccessInfo() => _hasAccess;
}

public class AnotherPerson : IPerson
{
    private readonly int _points;

    public AnotherPerson(string name, int points)
    {
        Name = name;
        _points = points;
    }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public int GetNumberOfPoints() => _points;
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var people = new List<IPerson>
        {
            new SomePerson("Angie", true),
            new AnotherPerson("Frank", 3),
            new SomePerson("Bill", false),
            new AnotherPerson("Sally", 9)
        };

        foreach (var person in people)
        {
            switch (person)
            {
                case SomePerson p:
                    Console.WriteLine(p.GetAccessInfo()
                        ? $"{p.Name} has access."
                        : $"{p.Name} does not have access.");
                    break;
                case AnotherPerson p:
                    Console.WriteLine($"{p.Name} has {p.GetNumberOfPoints()} points.");
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: `switch (person)`? where is it `person` defined?

Comment: `person` is the `foreach` loop variable, representing the current item from the `people` list.

Comment: Yes, that's definitely doable. In C# you can also use the `is` and `as` keywords to do type checking.

Answer (score 0):

I hate to flag posts for closing because every question is unique and has variation plus every post attracts potentially different experts but check this  [post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42041294/841330) on StackOverflow which is very similar and the answer is visitor pattern.